# Recorrer un JSON en Python

Tags: python-3.x, json

Quiero aprender a recorrer un JSON y cambiarle algunos valores, por favor alguna idea de como seria. Por ejemplo tengo este JSON y cambiar el `"type": "number"` por `"type": "int"` y sí es `"type": "string"` a `"type": "keywords"`

El archivo lo abrí así:

```
cadena_json = json.load(open('Personas_atendidas_en_la_subsecretaria_de_desarrollo_rural.json',encoding="utf8"))
```

El contenido del archivo es:

```
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "EDAD",
        "type": "number",
        "format": "default",
        "constraints": {"required": false},
        "description": "Edad de la persona registrada"
    },
    {
        "name": "SEXO",
        "type": "string",
        "format": "default",
        "constraints": {"required": false},
        "description": "Sexo de la persona registrada"
    },
```

Comment: Esto te será de mucha utilidad: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/pythonya/ y https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

una vez cargado el *json* en la variable `cadena_json` su contenido sería un diccionario como el que contiene el archivo fuente.

Por lo tanto, debes acceder a la llave `fields` y luego iterar la lista de diccionarios que contiene esa llave, lo cual se podria hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
for field_dict in cadena_json['fields']:
    if field_dict['type'] == 'number':
        field_dict['type'] = 'int'
```

Eso lo haces para todas las condiciones que quieras y al final de la iteracion de la lista de campos, el diccionario `cadena_json` tendrá los cambios que hiciste en su contenido.

Comment: Excelente ayuda, ya podre iterar sobre los demas valores, tus conocimientos son muy solidos gracias.