# Web Scraping - Does not show results

Tags: python, scraping, beautifulsoup, find

Saben porque me trae 0 data cuando llamo de la siguiente forma

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = 'https://inkafarma.pe/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://inkafarma.pe/categoria/cuidado-personal/cuidado-bucal-1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xxl-3 mb-3 ng-star-inserted')

productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='')

print (productlist)
```

Me muestra lo siguiente: []

El div del que quiero llamar es el siguiente:

```
<div _ngcontent-fxg-c19="" class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xxl-3 mb-3 ng-star-inserted">
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

lo que sucede es que ese contenido es generado dinamicamente por javascript
puedes validar esto dando un click derecho ver codigo fuente de la pagina.

afortunadamente cuenta con un llamado a un json.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = 'https://inkafarma.pe/'
headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://5doa19p9r7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/PROD/department-tree?keyword=cuidado-bucal-1')

#soup =BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
#productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4')
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Si necesariamente quiero que me filtre el ProductList

Comment: es un json...  si necesitas mas informacion puedes dar click derecho->inpecionar->network->actualizas la pagina...  hay veras todas las llamadas a url que hace y buscas aquello que deses! [recorrer json python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/296154/recorrer-un-json-en-python)